# UIActionSheet show black line while presenting on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiactionsheet

UIActionSheet' was displaying properly in my one of the application until iOS 7 release. But now when I open UIActionSheet in iOS 7, it shows black line` on top corner of action sheet. As you can see in below image [image: action sheet with black line in corners]

After spending ample amount of time to find its reason, Finally I found that if we display `UIActionSheet title` (set title property with some text) then those black line removed by iOS 7. like image [image: Action sheet with title]

But As per requirement I don't want to display UIActionSheet title. So Is there any other approach to remove those black lines in corner? Or its an iOS 7 bug?

```
- (IBAction) showActionsheetWithoutTitle:(id)sender {
     UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]   initWithTitle:@""  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2",@"Button3", nil];
     [actionsheet showInView:self.view];}
```

Comment: I was unable to replicate the black line on action sheet in iOS 7.1, can you please share your code.

Comment: Added code in original post.

Comment: replace @"" with nil for initWithTitle, as it takes a small gap between the title and other buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace @"" with nil for initWithTitle, as it takes a small gap between the title and other buttons:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2",@"Button3",  nil];
```